# Amazon web services S3 access denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am having problems accessing my aws S3 server bucket from my app. I get a request in the bucket log files, but access is denied.
I have and inline policy and a managed policy allowing full access to the server, as well as having set the server permission to allow everybody, but it still says access denied.
An identity of the right pool was created too.
At the app end I get a message that the bucket wasn't found.
The server region is London.

I have read a lot of the other questions regarding the issue, but none of them solved my problem.

Thank you

Inline unauthenticated IAM policy

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt1488834891000",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:*"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::ascentserver/*"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

for some reason this didn't work on the policy simulator, I tried adding the resources for bucket and service, didn't help.

Managed Policy is default S3 full access and simulates as working.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Code snippet addressing the server:

```
public void setFileToUpload(){

       TransferObserver transferObserver = transferUtility.upload(
                "http://ascentserver.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com",     /* The bucket to upload to */
                "TEST.png",    /* The key for the uploaded object */
                fileToUpload       /* The file where the data to upload exists */
        );

       transferObserverListener(transferObserver);
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps it'd be better if you could provide more info that would allow others to help you, such as the type of your app, where/how it is hosted, AWS SDK you're using or the code snippet that's making the S3 request, the IAM policies you're using and to which entities you're attaching and the URL pattern you're using when accessing the S3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide the bucket name as `ascentserver` instead of `http://ascentserver.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com` for the `transferUtility.upload()` method and make sure `AmazonS3Client` uses the correct region and not the default one by explicitly setting the endpoint as `s3.setEndpoint("s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com")`.

For example:

```
CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
    getApplicationContext(),    
    "YOUR_COGNITO_POOL_ID",    
    Regions.EU_WEST_2           
);

AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client(credProvider);
s3.setEndpoint("s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com");

TransferUtility transferUtility = new TransferUtility(s3, getApplicationContext());

TransferObserver transferObserver = transferUtility.upload(
    "ascentserver",
    "TEST.png",
    fileToUpload
);

.
.
.
```

Comment: Doing that gives us the error of "The bucket must address the specified endpoint" and it still fails to access the server.

Comment: You need make sure `AmazonS3Client` uses the correct region and not the default one by explicitly setting the endpoint as `s3.setEndpoint("s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com")`.  See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

So the code we have been using is the following:
*note these are just snippets, not the entire code*

[in the main]

```
import com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferListener;
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferObserver;
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferState;
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferUtility;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Region;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client;

import java.io.File;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

File fileToUpload = new     File("/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Screenshots/TEST.png");
File fileToDownload = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Download/TEST");
AmazonS3 s3;
TransferUtility transferUtility;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    // callback method to call credentialsProvider method
    credentialsProvider();

    // callback method to call the setTransferUtility method
    setTransferUtility();
}

public void credentialsProvider(){

    // Initialize the Amazon Cognito credentials provider
    CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
            getApplicationContext(),
            "eu-west-1:0e33dea3-6075-4ea5-a268-b0c1364f5107", // Identity Pool ID
            Regions.EU_WEST_1 // Region
    );

    setAmazonS3Client(credentialsProvider);
}

public void setAmazonS3Client(CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider){

    // Create an S3 client
    s3 = new AmazonS3Client(credentialsProvider);

    // Set the region of your S3 bucket
    s3.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_1));

}

public void setTransferUtility(){

    transferUtility = new TransferUtility(s3, getApplicationContext());
}

public void setFileToUpload(){

    TransferObserver transferObserver = transferUtility.upload(
            "http://ascentserver.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com",     /* The bucket to upload to */
            "TEST.png",    /* The key for the uploaded object */
            fileToUpload       /* The file where the data to upload exists */
    );

    transferObserverListener(transferObserver);
}

public void setFileToDownload(){

    TransferObserver transferObserver = transferUtility.download(
            "http://ascentserver.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com",     /* The bucket to download from */
            "TEST.png",    /* The key for the object to download */
            fileToDownload        /* The file to download the object to */
    );

    transferObserverListener(transferObserver);

}

public void transferObserverListener(TransferObserver transferObserver){

    // listener that provides status of download
    transferObserver.setTransferListener(new TransferListener(){

        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(int id, TransferState state) {
            Log.e("statechange", state+"");
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(int id, long bytesCurrent, long bytesTotal) {
            int percentage = (int) (bytesCurrent/bytesTotal * 100);
            Log.e("percentage",percentage +"");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(int id, Exception ex) {
            Log.e("error","error");
        }

    });
}
}
```

[Dependencies]

```
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.2.13'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.2.13'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.2.13'
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb:2.2.13'
```

[Manifest]

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<service
        android:name="com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferService"
        android:enabled="true" />
```